# How can I repair my code because I can't get my browser request to go through these proxies and header?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, request, urllib

I've gotten my code to unload a txt file with proxies but can't seem to figure out why its not being used as a proxy, as well as when the proxy was working the header wouldn't let proxy work.

Things to Know:

I used Grabify to See my Header and ip/port.
Most of the unused imports are from other testing.
Any help is appreciated.

```
 import urllib3, json, re, requests, random, os, subprocess as sp, time 

#imports ip:port from txt
proxies=[]
with open("C:\\Users\\David\\Downloads\\proxies.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        ip = re.findall(r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}:[0-9]+', line)
        proxies.append(ip)
    print("Proxies Gathered From List....")

#browser Function
def browse(url, ip):
    browser = ['C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome', url,
    '--proxy-server={ip}'.format(ip=ip)]
    #'--user-agent=(Mozilla/15.2 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106     Safari/537.36)']

    browserr = sp.Popen(browser)
    time.sleep(1)
    browserr.terminate()

#Testing
url_link = "https://grabify.link/YKM49H"
FinIP=proxies[int(random.randint(1,len(proxies)-1))]
print(*FinIP)
browse(url_link, *FinIP)
```

Goals:

Trying to open a link in google chrome w/ Proxy & Custom Header

Comment: you might need to escape or quote the ip and headers?, try to copy and paste the contents of the `browser` variable, aka the `...\chrome url --proxy... --user` part into cmd prompt. what happens?

Comment: @jmunsch I've tried, doesn't seem like it loads any of my arguments(unless im doing it wrong that is) "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Google Chrome.lnk" https://grabify.link/YKM49H --proxy-server=208.79.177.53:8080

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What did you expect to happen and what happens instead? Your code has numerous small bugs in it, but it's not immediately clear which one, if any of them, is the problem

Comment: @Iguananaut the proxy and custom header arnt working, it provides my own ip and regular chrome header.

Comment: Yeah, but have you done anything to narrow down where the problem is?  In what way is it "not working".  Have you ensure that the arguments passed to chrome are exactly what you expect them to be?  What debugging steps have you tried?

Comment: @Iguananaut, im not an intelligent moron that posts something without debugging.Yes I added and removed parts(header, proxy). I've done this in 2-3 different ways. This is where I am, the proxy and header are not working. It sends MY ip, and MY own browser header.

Comment: What is "it" in that last sentence?

Comment: @Iguananaut, the script? lol